# Is it possible to get an intersection or a diff of two result sets in YQL?

Tags: sql, twitter, yql

I need to build a Twitter module entirely on the client side.

I intended to use the [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/) for the data and [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) to get across [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), and also for its higher rate limiting. I have used this combination before with success.

One thing I need to do is to get a list of tweets with a hashtag and from a finite set of users.

[This gets tweets with the `#stackoverflow` hash tag by users `alexdickson` and `lizardbill`.](https://twitter.com/#!/search/#stackoverflow%20from%3aalexdickson,%20OR%20from%3alizardbill)

I also need to get a different set of tweets.

[This gets all tweets with the `#stackoverflow` hash tag.](https://twitter.com/#!/search/#stackoverflow)

Now, I need to display the second collection but excluding the results from the first set. This would be a *diff* of the results, like PHP's [`array_diff()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php).

For completeness, I may also need to achieve something by getting an intersection of two results, that is, a list of tweets which appear in both result sets. This is similar to PHP's [`array_intersect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php).

It has been a while since I've used SQL and can't think of how to achieve this in YQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YQL supports sub-selects (subqueries). See [Joining Tables with Sub-selects](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/joins.html). Sub-selects are used with the [`IN` operator](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/filters.html#in_operator), to filter the results of the outer select.

For your particular query, there is also a `twitter.search` [Community Open Data Table](http://datatables.org) available to save you from building the Twitter URLs and using the `json` table.

```
select *
from twitter.search
where q="#stackoverflow" 
and id not in (
    select id 
    from twitter.search 
    where q="#stackoverflow from:alexdickson, OR from:lizardbill"
)
```

<sup>([Try this query in the YQL console](http://y.ahoo.it/zIp7T).)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I finally got it. YQL supports sub-queries.

```
SELECT results 
FROM   json 
WHERE  url = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23stackoverflow" 
       AND results.id NOT IN (SELECT results.id 
                              FROM   json 
                              WHERE  url = 
"http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23stackoverflow%20from%3aalexdickson,%20OR%20from%3alizardbill" 
)
```

[YQL Console](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select%20results%20from%20json%20where%20url=%22http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%2523stackoverflow%22%20and%20results.id%20not%20in%20%28select%20results.id%20from%20json%20where%20url=%22http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%2523stackoverflow%2520from%253aalexdickson,%2520OR%2520from%253alizardbill%22%20%29).

Comment: You could also make use of the `twitter.search` community table in a similar manner.  `select * from twitter.search where q="#stackoverflow" and id not in (select id from twitter.search where q="#stackoverflow from:alexdickson, OR from:lizardbill")`

Comment: @salathe Thanks for that. I never noticed the community tables. If you post that as an answer, I'll accept :)